# How to optimize performance of postgresql query ? Whether stored procedure, function, materialized view or normalized tables are better option?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have three tables which a huge size approximate row count as follows.

- table  1 -  250,000,000 rows
- table 2 - 140,273,485
- table 3 - 453,516,490

Currently I am using below query to fetch data from PostgreSQL.

All the above tables are indexed tables based on selection. But found that query is not performing well as expected.
Which is taking more than 10 seconds or for few inputs it is taking minutes to fetch output.

How can i optimize this query to perform well in web request in spring boot application.

Do I need use PostgreSQL stored procedure, function, materialized view or de-normalized table. Which one can perform better than query?

Found the few scenario's output has has 1 billion rows for few conditions.

Some cases found that entire db is going out of memory, how to handle this.

Please find the query:

```
select t1.value1 AS v1,
            t2.value2 as v2,
            t1.value3 as v3,
            t1.v4  as v4, 
            t1.value5  as v5,
            t3.value6 as v6,
            t1.value7  as v7 
from db.table1 t1 
   left outer join db.table2 t2  on t1.value1 = t2.value1 
   left outer join db.table3 t3 
            on t2.value2 = t3.value2 
where t1.value6 IN  ('x','y') 
where  t1.v4 = ?
```

Condition changes according to input values

Comment: Without the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) and your DML, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have EXACTLY those indexes :

```
CREATE INDEX X1 ON table1 (V4, value6, value1) INCLUDE (value3, value5, value7);
CREATE INDEX X2 ON table2 (value1, value2);
CREATE INDEX X3 ON table3 (value2) INCLUDE (value6);
```

?

Comment: currently i have index on following data                                                                  
table1 indexed on value3,v4,value5
table2 indexed on value1
table3 indexed on value1 and value2

Comment: And the INCLUDE clause ?